# How to write to a specific location in a file

Tags: file, go

I'm writing a command line tool to help me scaffold my projects. I need to be able to add a line of text to a file but to a specific location. Here is the example:

I have this `routes.js` file:

```
router.map({
  '/home':{
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  '/about':{
    name: 'about',
    component: About
  },
  '/quote':{
    name: 'quote',
    component: Quote
  }
})
```

Now I want to run a command to create a new route so `my-cli generate route ExampleRoute`

And I would like it to write the route like so:

```
router.map({
    '/home':{
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
    '/about':{
    name: 'about',
    component: About
  },
    '/quote':{
    name: 'quote',
    component: Quote
  },
    '/example-route':{
    name: 'example-route',
    component: ExampleRoute
  }
})
```

Appending to the bottom of a file is easy but how do I write to a specific location?

Comment: By definition, "append" means write at the end of the file. What do mean by "append to a specific location"? You can't insert bytes into the middle of a file without rewriting it.

Comment: @JimB Sorry I miss phrased my question I just want to be a able to write to a specific location in a file

Comment: To write at a specific location, you seek to that location first: [`File.Seek`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek)

Comment: Have you looked at gotemplate to see if it would work in your situation?

Comment: Regardless of the OS or programming language, this is a limitation of general "file" access semantics. You can't easily *insert* data into a file, because you can't *move* data (after the insertion point).

Comment: os.File implements the io.WriterAt interface. What problem are you having trying to write to a specific place in a file? It should be at easy as FileVariableName.WriteAt(bytes to write, offset).

Comment: @driusan the issue is the location changes each time so I don't know how to find the byte location

Comment: @user3666882: this is why when you edit a file, you overwrite the file, or replace the old file with a new file. Unless this is a very very large file that changes frequently (e.g. a database), there's no point in trying to edit it byte by byte in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small files like this it is best to read the file into memory, modify it, and write it back out again.

One possibility is to read it in to a list of strings, one per line. Then insert the added lines into the list.  Then write out the list back to the file.

Another possibility would be to parse the file into a map, insert the new elements into the map, and then write the contents of the map out to the file in the required format.

Alternatively if you always want to insert the new text at a fixed offset from the end of the file, you could read into a string, and insert your new text at the end, like so:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

const textToInsert = `,
'/example-route':{
name: 'example-route',
component: ExampleRoute
  }
})
`

func main() {
    original, err := ioutil.ReadFile("routes.js")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // replace last 4 characters with textToInsert
    modified := append(original[0:len(original)-4], []byte(textToInsert)...)

    err = ioutil.WriteFile("routes.js", modified, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```